# How to get rid of indentation after align block in beamer (stays even with noindent)

Tags: beamer, indentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Was heißt \(\ket{u_j}\)?}
\only<1->{
    Dazu beachte zunächst:
    \begin{align*}
        \ket{0} &\coloneqq \ket{0\times 2^1+0\times 2^0} \coloneqq \ket{00}\coloneqq \ket{0}\ket{0}\coloneqq \ket{0}\otimes\ket{0}\\
        \ket{1} &\coloneqq \ket{0\times 2^1+1\times 2^0}\coloneqq \ket{01}\coloneqq \ket{0}\ket{1}\coloneqq \ket{0}\otimes\ket{1}\\
        \ket{2} &\coloneqq \ket{1\times 2^1+0\times 2^0}\coloneqq \ket{10}\coloneqq \ket{1}\ket{0}\coloneqq \ket{1}\otimes\ket{0}\\
        \ket{3} &\coloneqq \ket{1\times 2^1+1\times 2^0}\coloneqq \ket{11}\coloneqq \ket{1}\ket{1}\coloneqq \ket{1}\otimes\ket{1}
    \end{align*}
}\only<2->{
    \noindent Insbesondere gilt \(\ket{k}\) orthonormal für \(k\in\mathbb{N}\), und \(\ket{0},\dots,\ket{N-1}\) benötigt \(n=\log_2{N}\) bits. D.h.
    \begin{align*}
        u_j=\sum_{i=0}^N u_{ij} e_i \implies \ket{u_j}=\sum_{i=0}^N u_{ij}\ket{i}
    \end{align*}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

results in [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linefeed character after your second `only` command is interpreted by latex and inserts a single interword space at the beginning of the next line. You can make the linefeed invisible without changing the structure of your `.tex` file if you insert a comment directly after the opening brace of the `only` directive:

```
\only<2->{%....
...
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Was heißt \(\ket{u_j}\)?}
\only<1->{
    Dazu beachte zunächst:
    \begin{align*}
        \ket{0} &\coloneqq \ket{0\times 2^1+0\times 2^0} \coloneqq \ket{00}\coloneqq \ket{0}\ket{0}\coloneqq \ket{0}\otimes\ket{0}\\
        \ket{1} &\coloneqq \ket{0\times 2^1+1\times 2^0}\coloneqq \ket{01}\coloneqq \ket{0}\ket{1}\coloneqq \ket{0}\otimes\ket{1}\\
        \ket{2} &\coloneqq \ket{1\times 2^1+0\times 2^0}\coloneqq \ket{10}\coloneqq \ket{1}\ket{0}\coloneqq \ket{1}\otimes\ket{0}\\
        \ket{3} &\coloneqq \ket{1\times 2^1+1\times 2^0}\coloneqq \ket{11}\coloneqq \ket{1}\ket{1}\coloneqq \ket{1}\otimes\ket{1}
    \end{align*}
}\only<2->{%
    Insbesondere gilt \(\ket{k}\) orthonormal für \(k\in\mathbb{N}\), und \(\ket{0},\dots,\ket{N-1}\) benötigt \(n=\log_2{N}\) bits. D.h.
    \begin{align*}
        u_j=\sum_{i=0}^N u_{ij} e_i \implies \ket{u_j}=\sum_{i=0}^N u_{ij}\ket{i}
    \end{align*}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you tell me why a linefeed is all of the sudden interpreted as a whitespace? It usually does not do that in text, and shouldn't noindent remove that? Additionally beamer sets indentation to zero by default anyway. So this is really odd behavior

Comment: Latex maps a single linefeed character to a single interword space. If you think of the `only` directive in your document as being a box, than the first character that is seen by latex is a linefeed character. This is why the printed output of the box starts with an interword space. You can test it by inserting `\mbox{<linefeed>insbesondere gilt...}` in any other document and you will get the same effect.

Comment: oh so it has to do with the brackets `{` and not the line break?

Comment: It's because the first character parsed after the bracket is a linefeed character or more generally a whitespace. A single space or tab directly after the bracket would produce the same effect. We tend to not see linebreaks as characters but on the level of data processing they are.